# MySQL program cannot find -lmysqld error

Tags: c++, mysql, gnu-make

I'm compiling [Cryptdb](https://github.com/CryptDB/cryptdb) in my ubuntu 16.04, which uses -lmysqld option. My MySQL version is 5.5.52; The program reports the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqld
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have followed the instruction in [Mysql Installation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/installing-source-distribution.html)
to install mysql, including using make install to copy some .h file to /usr/local/mysql/...; So I wounder how to make -lmysqld work.

Also, the program uses such files as select_sql.h, which does not appear in /user/local/mysql/...; Currently, I have to find those files in the mysql source code directory: ./mysql-5.5.52/sql and add -I option in Makefile, can anyone find a more elegant way?

Thanks:)

Comment: install `libmysqld-dev`. That is, if you have mysql from the repositories.

Comment: Thanks:) It works correctly.